# Why do I have two different product ids on the same product in my data Layer?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I have a problem with product ids values on my data layer. When I checked Purchase data layer I could see ecommerce data layer section that looks like bellow:

```
ecommerce: {
    currencyCode: "EUR",
    purchase: {
      actionField: {
        id: "394299",
        affiliation: "",
        revenue: 0,
        tax: 0,
        shipping: 0,
        coupon: "test999"
      },
      products: [
        {
          id: 296,
          name: "Test Name",
          sku: "STR99",
          category: "Housewarming",
          price: 0,
          stocklevel: null,
          quantity: 1
        },
        {
          id: 393,
          name: "Test Name2",
          sku: "MN61",
          category: "Wedding",
          price: 0,
          stocklevel: null,
          quantity: 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

So I see that Test Name's ID equal to 296 and Test Name2 id equal to 393. But when I am on a product page for example on Test Name product page in data Layer I see that value of **ecomm_prodid** key equals to 484.

I compare it to ID that I could find in Woocomerce admin panel and it looks like the ID from ecomm_prodid key is valid. So the question is why am I seeing different value in Purchase data layer. And on Purchase I don't have valid one and unvalid. I only have one that i unvalid. Data Layer is implemented by wordpress plugins.

Comment: It doesn't seem like there's enough information here to help you.

Comment: I am using GTM4WP plugin. What could I check to discover why such situation occurs?

Comment: This sounds more like a question for plug-in support than for stack overflow.

Comment: Can we take a look at the products csv or the whole datalayer in your product page? Not sure why you look at the 'ecomm_prodid' in the product page. There should be an ecommerce object as well but contain detail